# UltraVNC fails with OCR, RDC succeeds

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, ocr

I am trying to use OCR on a remote machine, which can be connected to via either RDC or VNC.

There is one script that is supposed to run there, that is using tesseract OCR package.

For some reason the VNC server and script fails, it does not detect the letters correctly and does not detect numbers at all.

In RDC everything works super smooth.

The env. is Win7. And I struggle to understand what is the difference between these two methods that they change the graphical side of the machine so that one can detect and the other struggles. Does RDC have some text enhancers enabled?